# Select specific elements from json array using swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I am displaying some data from json array but it is printing whole array creating exactly that number of cells of json array length. I want to show specific data then how can i do that?

here is my json link:
    https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

I want to show title of those data whose albumId = 1

Here is my code:

```
class PhotosByAlbumViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var albumId:Int = 1 // It is my album ID
var allImages: [Any] = []
let urlForData = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    callToFetchJson()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func callToFetchJson() {

    let request = URLRequest(url: urlForData!)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if data == nil && error != nil {
            print("No Data")
        }
        else if data != nil && error != nil {
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.decodingJson(data!)
            }

        }
        }.resume()
}


func decodingJson(_ data: Data ) {
    do {
        let allImage = data
        allImages = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allImage, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [Any]
        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
    catch {

    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: 150 , height: 180)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.allImages.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "albumPhotoCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! albumPhotoCollectionViewCell

    let aImg:[String: AnyObject] = allImages[indexPath.item] as! [String: AnyObject]
    cell.imageDescription.text = (aImg["title"] as! String)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

}
}
```

Comment: I looked at your JSON link, it takes like 10 seconds to load.  Could you move a small sample of that JSON into the question rather than providing a link that may be dead in a few days?

Comment: @akousmata I think your Internet connectivity is slow. Improve man

Comment: It won't be dead. I found this link as fake json api. These links are there for testing any product using json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter your array after deserialization. This should be enough :

```
func decodingJson(_ data: Data ) {
    do {
        let allImage = data
        allImages = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allImage, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [Any]
        allImages = allImages.filter { $0["albumId"] == albumId }
        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
    catch {

    }

}
```

After adding this line, only elements with `"albumId" : 1` should be included in your `allImages` array.

Comment: I found my solution. I can do this in url: urlForData(URL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?albumId=\(albumId)") in viewdidload

Comment: By the way Thanks for your answer

Comment: No problem! If I knew your API supported such querry, I'd have suggested it. Generally its best to offload as much business logic/heavy tasks to the backend.

Comment: You are correct. First to fetch all 5000 results then filter them to 50 is heavy task rather we try to fetch 50 results only.

Comment: Well, if you or your team develops the backend, you could also implement pagination - in time the number of results where `albumId=1` may also grow.

Comment: Yeah sure we implement that. But as I was practising UICollectionView in iOS so this is the first fake json I got on google.